# git remote cluster & laptop setup for one developer -- why a "bare" repository?

Tags: git

I'm a Mercurial user.  I'm migrating to git for reasons I won't get into.

I'm mostly a development team of one, although the possibility of collaborators exists in the future.  I've used Mercurial in the past to keep track of changes and also to manage development of the same codebase on my laptop as well as a university cluster.

In Mercurial, to keep both my laptop and the cluster up to date I'd create a repository on my laptop, clone it to the cluster,and then push from (if I'd been working on my laptop) or pull to (if I'd been working on the cluster) my laptop and merge as necessary.

I've successfully migrated my mercurial repositories to git. From reading many git discussions on the web, it looks like I then (paraphrasing http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/)

```
ssh me@university_cluster.edu
mkdir my_project.git
cd my_project.git
git init --bare
git update-server-info # I skipped this
exit
```

and then on my laptop:

```
cd my_project
git remote add origin me@university_cluster.edu:my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

My questions, then:

This seems more complicated than it was in Mercurial.  Is this really the "best practice" approach for this?  I thought the whole idea with distributed source control (DSC) is that repositories talk to each other directly and merging is easy. Why the "middle man" approach with a git "bare" repository?  It seems like this results in having to maintain two directories on the remote machine (bare repository and working repository) and perform twice as many "transactions" every time I need to switch from one platform to the other.  That is, every laptop<->cluster switch involves pushing to the remote bare repository and then pulling from the remote bare repository, where before I'd just push (if finishing on my laptop) or pull (if starting on my laptop).

I hope I'm not inviting a Mercurial/Git flame war, I'm just trying to understand the git philosophy with this.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't update a remote repo's working copy when you push changes.  (That keeps a lot of things simpler, and the remote repo's owner doesn't have files changing right in front of him.)  A non-bare repo would see its head and working copy out of sync with every push.  So Git won't push to a non-bare repo unless you force it to.